# Google Charts API: Highlighting closest Datapoints between 2 series. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google line chart that contains a few years of data. Each year is a separate series. The chart legends displaying each year/series are clickable and clicking on any given 2 or more of these legends/series, displays them and their corresponding Datapoints and their annotations. In the hAxis, these Datapoints are integers ranging from 1 to aprox. 6,000,000. I also have their values displayed under annotations for each Datapoint.

Notice that when you click on a datapoint, it increases in size and gains a white border. If you unclick it, it returns to it's original form.

**My question is:**

Is it possible to change my code to look for the top 10 closest-to-each-other integers between 2 series based on a predefined threshhold? ***I know styling may not be an option but perhaps there may be a way to force a Datapoint to appear clicked.***

Please allow me to illustrate it for better understanding.

[image: As you can see, 1997 and 1998 and currently select. This chart display the desried outcome.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using option `selectionMode: 'multiple'` and selecting appropriate points using `setSelection()` method. For example:

```
        chart.setSelection([
            {row:0, column:1},
            {row:0, column:2},
            {row:2, column:1},
            {row:2, column:2}
        ]);
```

Of course, you will have to find out points which correspond to defined threshold. See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muzev/1/edit).

**Update:** [example with DataView](http://jsbin.com/muzev/2/edit).

Comment: Alright. You code works but my code is loading the chart from a View. Whenever I use a View it does not work. It does not crash either, but it does not work as intended. How would you accomplish the same thing while using a View to created the chart?

Comment: Do you mean DataView object or something else?

Comment: DataView, yes. Correct.

Comment: Updated with example with DataView. But there is no much difference. Question is what is your code.